# system language and system locale of mac?

Tags: objective-c, macos

Can you suggest me the API to get the system language and system locale of mac 10.3.9 version using cocoa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is available from 10.4, so tat would not help me,

I used

CFLocaleRef cflocale = CFLocaleCreateCopy(NULL, CFLocaleCopyCurrent());

Answer (score 1):

Try [NSLocale](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html)-  Not sure if it works in 10.3.9

Comment: "Available in Mac OS X v10.4 and later."